# Understanding Karlin's Proof of Perron's Theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Reading a proof of Perron's Theorem I got stuck at some place:

We have proved that spectral radius $\rho$ is a simple eigenvalue. Now we have to check that there are no eigenvalues other than spectral radius of modulus $\rho$.

Consider $A − \epsilon I > 0$ for small $\epsilon > 0$. Its largest positive
eigenvalue is $\rho − \epsilon$, which we have proved to be its spectral radius.

**Translating this smaller circle back to the right by $\epsilon$ we see that all remaining eigenvalues of $A$ lie within the open disk $|λ| < ρ$.**

I can't understand the above line(bold), Help Needed!

Ref: [The Many Proofs and Applications of Perron's Theorem](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0036144599359449) pg496.

Comment: MO copy: [Understanding Karlin's Proof of Perron's Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292491)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: any eigenvalues of $A$ must satisfy $|\lambda| \leq \rho$ **and** $|\lambda - \epsilon| \leq \rho - \epsilon$. The only complex number which satisfies both $|\lambda| = \rho$ **and** $|\lambda - \epsilon| \leq \rho - \epsilon$ is $\lambda = \rho$.

Comment: i think instead of $|\lambda - \epsilon| \leq \rho - \epsilon$ in the last line we should have $|\lambda - \epsilon| = \rho - \epsilon$

Comment: @user8795 No, I did this intentionally.  This part of the proof is about eigenvalues satisfying $|\lambda| = \rho$, but all eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $|\lambda - \epsilon| \leq \rho - \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Translating the smaller circle corresponds to undoing the operation $A - \varepsilon I$, in terms of the eigenvalues. That is, if in the complex plane you draw a point for each eigenvalue of $A - \varepsilon I$, then moving them all to the right by $\varepsilon$ gives you the eigenvalues of $A$. Since all of them are inside the circle of radius $\rho - \varepsilon$, when you move them, the only way there can be an eigenvalue in the boundary of the circle of radius $\rho$ is to have it at the positive real axis, i.e. at $\rho$.